# What abut this crazy sequence of loops and ifs? Ideas to improve this code?

Tags: python, optimization, loops, if-statement

This code is currently working, but it looks terrible - and probably can be much improved in terms of performance.

Any Suggestions?

```
def OnClick():
    global Selection, touch, set_elsb, set_vreg, set_els, BAR_Items
    A = viz.pick(0, viz.WORLD, all=False)
    if touch != A: return
    for i in BAR_Items:
        if not set_els: break
        elif BAR_Items[i] == A or SHAPES[i+"_SHP"] == A:
            if i in Selection:
                Selection.remove(i)
                BAR_Items[i].clearActions()
                VFrame.SetStatusText(frame, i + " has been deselected")
                viz.director( do_chart )
            else:
                Selection.append(i)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the goal of the code?

Comment: All I can see is a `for` with a an `if` and a nested `if`. Nothing outrageous performance wise, believe me I've seen worst.

Comment: can any of the functions called in the loop affect `set_els`? It's tough to modify code that uses so many globals without knowing what the globals are and how different elements affect them. This is sort of one of the major problems with globals.

Comment: @aaronasterling: none of the functions within the loop can change set_els state. I am using it as a flag to execute the  loop or not. What bothers me about this code the most, is that I feel like I am making a search when I already know what I am searching for (A).

Comment: @relima Are you showing us the whole function? if so, why not just handle checking `set_els` in the same way you handle `touch != A`? This would save doing that check on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: @aaronasterling: thanks. It is a shame I cannot upvote you.

Comment: so many globals. Is it necessary?

Comment: "probably can be much improved in terms of performance" - if you don't know for sure, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: One common thing for performance is to remove dots, like "remveselection = Selection.remove" before the loop and then "removeselection(i)" in the loop.  Also, is Selection something fast, like a set?  You are doing membership checking frequently...  Definitely remove the globals, possibly by making it a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a few more lines of code but I think it's clearer.

```
def OnClick():
     if not set_els: return

     # swap this with the line above if viz.pick has side effects that should occur 
     A = viz.pick(0, viz.WORLD, all=False) 
     if touch != A: return


     keys = (key for key in BAR_Items
             if BAR_Items[key] == A or SHAPES[key+"_SHP"] == A)

     for key in keys:
         if key in Selection:
             Selection.remove(key)
             BAR_Items[key].clearActions()
             VFrame.SetStatusText(frame, key + " has been deselected")
             viz.director(do_chart)
         else:
             Selection.append(key)
```

That entire `global` statement served no purpose as you weren't assigning to any of them. Calling attributes and setting keys don't require the `global` keyword.

Comment: keys = (key for key in BAR_Items if A in (BAR_Items[key], SHAPES[key+"_SHP"])

Comment: @hughdbrown, with constants, definitely. I'm not sure if the cost of constructing tuples from non-constants is offset by the gain of being able to use `in` and I think that both idioms are perfectly readable.

Answer (score 1):

My normal approach to this would be to re-factor some of it out into small methods. This generally makes it more testable and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If `set_els` is not changed outside during this code execution then:

```
def OnClick():
    global Selection, touch, set_elsb, set_vreg, set_els, BAR_Items
    if set_els: return
    A = viz.pick(0, viz.WORLD, all=False)
    if touch != A: return
    for i in BAR_Items:
        if not (BAR_Items[i] == A or SHAPES[i+"_SHP"] == A): continue
        if i in Selection:
            Selection.remove(i)
            BAR_Items[i].clearActions()
            VFrame.SetStatusText(frame, i + " has been deselected")
            viz.director( do_chart )
        else:
            Selection.append(i)
```

Anyway, my bad code detector flashes with red light when it sees such a code, especially with such amount of globals.

Answer (score 0):

It is very common to assume that if code is ugly, confusing, or hard to follow, it must therefore be inefficient.

Many people also think that if you want to make code go faster, you have to uglify it.

I've seen way ugly confusing code, some of which ran very fast, and other of which had massive performance problems.

I've also seen clean, clear, beautiful code of which the same could be said.

My experience - speed and beauty are independent.